# .net 4 string[] parameter default value setting

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to do like this:

```
public int Insert(object o, string[] ignore = new string[] {"Id"})
```

but it tells me that I can't do that ?
why is that so ?

Comment: Post your compiler error please :)

Comment: @Spence it just tells me that this is not allowed for reference types except for string, I'm just a little surprised that this was not implemented for some reason

Comment: "error CS1736: Default parameter value must be a compile-time constant". And that is the answer..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the default arguments must be constants. Here you are dynamically allocating an array. As with declaring `const` variables, for reference types only string literals and nulls are supported.

You can achieve this by using the following pattern

```
public int Insert(object o, string[] ignore = null)
{
  if (ignore == null) ignore = new string[] { "Id" };
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Now when the caller excludes the argument at the call site, the compiler will pass the value `null` which you can then handle as required. Note that jsut to keep it simple I have modified the value of the argument in the function, not generally considered good practice but I believe this might be alright in this scenario.

Comment: yes, i do Like this ignore = ignore ?? new[] {"Id"};, why couldn't .net dev team do this o_O

Comment: @Omu, for one, because it means you can't use `null` as a real value.  You can still do something similar with overloading.

Answer (score 6):

The only available default for reference types is null (except for string which also accepts literals) as it must be available at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to do it the .Net 1.1 way:

```
public int Insert(object o)
{
    return Insert(o, new String[] { "Id" });
}


public int Insert(object o, String[] s)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Actually it is c# 1 to 3.5 way... :)

Comment: And it has always been confusing. Perhaps not with two parameters, but with say 5 parameters that have should be optional, thats a lot of overloads...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an array why not use `params`?

```
public int Insert(object o, params string[] ignore)
{
    if (ignore == null || ignore.Length == 0)
    {
        ignore = new string[] { "Id" };
    }
    ...
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Insert(obj);

Insert(obj, "str");

Insert(obj, "str1", "str2");
```